# Collaboration using libgdx

Tags: java, eclipse, libgdx, collaboration, eclipse-neon

I am trying to collaborate on a libgdx project with team members. To test how everything works, I've been trying to clone random repositories from github with no luck... As a side note, i'm developing both Android and PC versions of the game

**Original Question:**
Can I simply create a github account and have my team download the repository, then have them push and pull every time we do work? I've only used github once, so i'm not very familiar in that aspect. However, I do know that Eclipse has a github addon. Though, since libgdx has a .jar file that generates a gradle project for you, which I had to import, i'm not sure if it will all work through github.

UPDATE: 
--The first answer stated, "yes" as an answer to my original question... however, I am having issues doing so. I'm not sure why I am getting the error in the below image when trying to clone a project. Any time I try cloning a repository (I have tried multiple random libdgx repo's on github), I get a similar error every time:

[image]

I'm mostly concerned about the gradle issue, but I also see that it is trying to reference drive V:\ which is just silly. I do not have that drive lol. What I did find similar between all of the projects that I tried to clone was that the gradle distribution is almost always different. Such as: gradle-2.12-all.zip or gradle-2.2-all.zip.

As a side note, I did set the path correctly to my Android SDK, it works for my other projects.[image]

I watched this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YCGmXVCvogY, and followed it exactly where he pulls his repository, and it doesn't work for me. Someone else the comments section had the same issue.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: "Can I simply create a github account and have my team download the repository, then have them push and pull every time we do work?" - yes.

Comment: @MitchWheat Sorry to pry, but I have to ask: have you done this with libdgx projects before? The information I read previously showed that it wasn't possible back in 2014. Also, if you are sure of your reply, why not post as an answer?

Comment: @MitchWheat So you're saying that they can generate a Java project in eclipse straight from my github repo? If so, please post as an answer so I can give you credit.

Comment: @MitchWheat I guess I was more or less worried about there being hidden files that won't be uploaded to github

Comment: I use Git for all my LibGDX projects. It works fine. LibGDX even comes with an appropriate .gitignore file when you generate a project. This keeps all the unnecessary project files and .jars out of your repository. Your team members merely need to clone your github repo and import the gradle project into Eclipse or IDEAS. Gradle takes care of downloading the appropriate .jars for them. If they want to work on the Android-specific portion, they need to have the Android SDK installed. I recommend you all use IDEAS...it seems to play nicer with Gradle, and is just easier all around.

Comment: @Tenfour04 Please take a look at my update

Comment: @MitchWheat Please take a look at my updated information, and thanks again for your time.

Comment: Every individual computer is different. The project setup in Eclipse or IDEAs cannot be shared between computers, and so it is not saved as part of your repo. Each individual on the team needs to configure their own development environment. They can clone your repo and then import the project as a Gradle project. It will be up to them to set up various SDKs properly on their computer.

Answer (score 0):

"Can I simply create a `github` account and have my team download the repository, then have them push and pull every time we do work?" - **Yes**, `github` simply stores files.

You can specify which files to not upload using a [`.gitignore`](https://help.github.com/articles/ignoring-files/) file.

There is a good, free git book [here](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2).

Comment: how does java usually handle importing such libraries?

Comment: er.. git is a distributed version control system, it will not configure your machine and IDE for dev, you must do it by yourself..

Comment: @Hllink Can you be more specific? Please see my updated question. I'd really appreciate it!

Comment: @FoxDonut,i think you're misunderstanding what git, subversion are for.They are used for collaboration for a team to share code/files, they will not configure your ambient, point the JDK, configure your eclipse plugins neither your project settings. Gradle will get the gradle configuration file and download all the dependencies jars from a repository for your project. Eclipse, Gradle, Git/Subversion are separated tools for different purposes.. Every machine needs their own configuration. In your case in the machine you are standing you didn't changed the android SDK location for your project.